# Mobile Chunked File HTTP Upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, mobile

Is it worth the development effort to chunk file (image) uploads from mobile devices over cell connections?  By *chunk* I mean making a series of independent HTTP post requests with different parts of the file and reassembling on the server.

Specifically, I've heard that mobile network connections may drop the connection before a file is uploaded completely (where it doesn't happen over wifi).  My hypothesis is that if I chunk the upload, the dropped connection will be less likely.  My concern is that in practice, it isn't more reliable, and now I've introduced latency.

Answer (score 0):

If the receiving end of the upload allows you to resume the upload at a particular chunk it could be very useful. This would allow you to minimize the impact of network errors by not having to restart the entire upload when an error is encountered.

For example, if you were using S3 as the backend you could leverage their [Multipart Upload](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/11/10/Amazon-S3-Introducing-Multipart-Upload/)

Comment: Agreed.  And while resumeable uploads may be implemented in the future, what I'm trying to get out now is more on _reliability_ -- does chunked uploads make the upload over HTTP more reliable.

Comment: @DavidFaivre Your results may vary but in the testing I have done it does not improve reliability and adds a performance penalty for doing chunked uploads, only way it became useful was with resume support.

Comment: Interesting.  My guess would have been that you would get some reliability improvement as you can decrease the request size (and reduce the chance that AT&T drops the connection).  But I'm an amateur with networking at best.  Thanks for input.